Syntax bug using sed
SOLVED: I did not realize using 'run' with multiple commands like I've done is chaining the commands together, and therefore any command that fails will make it look like the first line failed. I ended up switching to envsubst instead of sed anyway, much better for this use case.
I have a GitHub Actions workflow file where I'm using sed to replace variables within a configuration file, code below. The error I'm getting is with the GA_MP_SECRET line:
Run sed -i 's/${GA_MP_SECRET}/***/g' configs/myworkflow.yaml
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unknown option to `s'

At first I thought the path being inserted with ${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_YAML }} might be causing an issue due to the slash, but the first three sed lines (under "Modify app yaml basics") don't cause an error.
I tried moving consolidating all the sed lines from "Modify app yaml secrets" up underneath the 'Modify app yaml basics' sed lines, and suddenly the IMAGE_TAG sed line breaks, with the same error, even though it didn't cause an error before.
I figured there must be a hidden character or something breaking this, but I can't track anything down.
The workflow file:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    env:
      CONTAINER_APP_NAME: software-api-test
      LOCATION: central_us
      RESOURCE_GROUP: softwareDevRg
      ACR_NAME: softwareacr
      CONTAINER_APP_YAML: "configs/myworkflow.yaml"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Log into Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}

      - name: Modify app yaml basics
        run: |
          sed -i 's/${IMAGE_TAG}/${{ github.sha }}/g' ${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_YAML }}
          sed -i 's/${CONTAINER_APP_NAME}/${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_NAME }}/g' ${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_YAML }}
          sed -i 's/${RESOURCE_GROUP}/${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}/g' ${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_YAML }}

      - name: Modify app yaml secrets
        run: |
          sed -i 's/${GA_MP_SECRET}/${{ secrets.GA_MP_SECRET }}/g' ${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_YAML }}
          sed -i 's/${FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}/${{ secrets.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}/g' ${{ env.CONTAINER_APP_YAML }}


What is IMAGE_TAG? Can it change between different runs? Could it contain characters that need to be escaped for sed?

What are the values of the variables? Shell variables are not expanded in single quotes by your shell.

@Manfred sed is replacing the string ${IMAGE_TAG} in the configuration file (not shown) with the GitHub.sha value, so shouldn't have any weird characters.

@knittl the first three sed commands are inserting the GitHub SHA and some of the env variables defined in the code I've included.
But those three sed commands are identical to the later ones, yet it's the fourth sed (the next section) that breaks. And if I consolidate all the seds into one step, the first sed command breaks. It doesn't make sense and I'm going crazy

@Max Do your token/secret values contain /, ', or a trailing backslash?

@knitti Some of the later ones do.. I was assuming that shouldn't matter since its new lines, but maybe i'm misunderstanding the Github actions run command. Is this chaining all of the sed commands together, similar to using && in terminal?

I did not realize using 'run' with multiple commands like I've done is chaining the commands together, and therefore any command that fails will make it look like the first line failed. Very weird IMO, but either way, it turns out there was a slash in one of the later lines.
I ended up switching to envsubst instead of sed anyway, much better for this use case. No issues anymore!
